# エラー原因がわかりません

Tags: java-ee

JavaEEで部署管理アプリを作成しています。
部署編集画面で新規データを入力し、新規作成ボタンを押した際に、エラー画面（あらかじめ用意していたもの）に遷移するようになってしまいます。
エラー原因がもし分かればご教授頂ければ幸いです。

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>部署編集</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/practice2016/css/practice2016.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="center">
            <h1>部署編集</h1>
        </div>
        <h:messages styleClass="facesMessage" errorClass="error" />
        <h:form>
            <div class="frame2">
                <div class="search">
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">ID</span>
                        <span class="input1"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.id}" disabled="#{editBean.disableId}" label="ID" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">部署番号</span>
                        <span class="input2"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.deptNo}" maxlength="9" label="部署番号" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">部署名</span>
                        <span class="input3"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.deptName}" maxlength="20" label="部署名" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">場所</span>
                        <span class="input4"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.loc}" maxlength="20" label="場所" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search2">
                    <h:commandButton class="return" action="#{editBean.back()}" value="戻る"/>
                    <h:commandButton class="save" action="#{editBean.save()}" value="保存"/>
                    <h:commandButton class="delete" action="#{editBean.delete()}" value="削除"  onclick="return confirm('削除しますか？');"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```
/**
 * 編集画面のバッキングBean
 */
@Model
@ViewScoped
public class EditBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private EditLogic logic;
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message="{errors.required}")
    private String deptName;

    @Min(value=1)
    @NotEmpty(message="{errors.required}")
    private Integer deptNo;

    private String loc;
    private Integer versionNo;
    private boolean disableId;

    /**
     * @return id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id セットする id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return deptName
     */
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    /**
     * @param deptName セットする deptName
     */
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    /**
     * @return deptNo
     */
    public Integer getDeptNo() {
        return deptNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param  セットする deptNo
     */
    public void setDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
    }
    /**
     * @return loc
     */
    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }
    /**
     * @param loc セットする loc
     */
    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }
    /**
     * @return versionNo
     */
    public Integer getVersionNo() {
        return versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param versionNo セットする versionNo
     */
    public void setVersionNo(Integer versionNo) {
        this.versionNo = versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @return disableId
     */
    public boolean isDisableId() {
        return disableId;
    }
    /**
     * @param disableId セットする disableId
     */
    public void setDisableId(boolean disableId) {
        this.disableId = disableId;
    }

    /**
     * 初期処理
     */
    @PostConstruct
    @Auth
    public void init(){
        if(FlashUtil.get("id") != null){
            this.setId(Long.valueOf(FlashUtil.get("id")));
            logic.init(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 戻るボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String back(){
        // 検索画面に戻る
        return "/views/dept/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    /**
     * 保存ボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String save(){
        logic.save(this);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage("", CommonUtil.getFacesInfoMessage("messages.add.complete"));
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 削除ボタン押下時処理
     * @param id
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String delete(){
        logic.delete(this);
        return back();
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * 編集画面のビジネスロジックI/F
 */
public interface EditLogic {
    /**
     * 初期処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    public void init(EditBean bean);

    /**
     * 保存処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    public void save(EditBean bean);

    /**
     * 削除処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    public void delete(EditBean bean);
}
```

```
/**
 * 編集画面のビジネスロジック
 */
@Stateless
public class EditLogicImpl implements EditLogic {

    @Inject
    private DeptDao dao;

    /**
     * 初期処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void init(EditBean bean){
        Long id = bean.getId();
        if(id != null){
            Dept dept = dao.findById(id);
            bean.setId(dept.getId());
            bean.setDeptName(dept.getDeptName());
            bean.setDeptNo(dept.getDeptNo());
            bean.setLoc(dept.getLoc());
            bean.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo());
            bean.setDisableId(true);
        }
        if(bean.getVersionNo() == null){
            bean.setVersionNo(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 保存処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void save(EditBean bean){
        Dept dept = new Dept();
        dept.setId(bean.getId());
        dept.setDeptName(bean.getDeptName());
        dept.setDeptNo(bean.getDeptNo());
        dept.setLoc(bean.getLoc());
        if(bean.getVersionNo() != null){
            dept.setVersionNo(bean.getVersionNo());
        }else{
        }

        if(bean.isDisableId()){
            // 更新
            dao.update(dept);
            bean.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo());
        }else{
            // 新規登録
            dao.insert(dept);
            bean.setDisableId(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 削除処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(EditBean bean){
        // 削除
        dao.delete(bean.getId());
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the DEPT database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Dept.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Dept d")
public class Dept implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
    private String deptName;

    @Column(name="DEPT_NO")
    private int deptNo;

    private String loc;

    @Column(name="VERSION_NO")
    private int versionNo;

    public Dept() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return this.deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public Integer getDeptNo() {
        return this.deptNo;
    }

    public void setDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return this.loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public Integer getVersionNo() {
        return this.versionNo;
    }

    public void setVersionNo(Integer versionNo) {
        this.versionNo = versionNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: `save()`メソッドのjavadocにの`@return 遷移先画面`と書いていますが、最終的に`return null;`していますね。これは意図した通りですか？この部分を`return "/views/dept/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";`に書き換えて、検索画面に戻れば、`return null;`に問題があると思います。検索画面に戻らなければ、それ以前の実装で何らかの例外が発生しているんだと思います。

Comment: kohei TAMURA様 いつもありがとうございます。検索画面に戻らなかったです。。となるとそれ以前の実装で何らかの例外が発生していることになりますよね。。その例外を確かめるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: デバッガーをアタッチすれば簡単なんですが。やり方が分からないようでしたら、`try～catch`＋`e.printStackTrace()`や`System.out.println()`を追加して、どこまで意図したとおりに動作しているか、標準出力に出力してみるのがいいかと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。String型でないdeptNoに@NotEmptyを用いていたのがエラーの原因でした。

Comment: そこでしたか。それでログにエラーが出ないんですかね... では時間のある時に、回答を書いておいてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String型でないdeptNoに@NotEmptyを用いていたのがエラーの原因でした。ありがとうございました。