# 入力値検証アノテーションによるエラー発生時

Tags: java-ee, jsf

JavaEEにてアプリ作成をしています。
入力値検証アノテーションを用いて、入力値のチェックをしているのですが、
エラーが発生した際に、戻るボタン等を押しても機能しなくなってしまいます。
エラー発生時でも、他のボタンが機能するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

```
/**
 * 編集画面のバッキングBean
 */
@Model
@ViewScoped
public class EditBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private EditLogic logic;

    @NotEmpty(message="{errors.required}")
    private String empCode;

    @NotEmpty(message="{errors.required}")
    private String name;

    @Pattern(regexp="^([\\w])+([\\w\\._-])*\\@([\\w])+([\\w\\._-])*\\.([a-zA-Z])+$")
    private String email;

    private Integer versionNo;

    private String editEmpCode;

    private boolean disableEmpCode;

    /**
     * @return empCode
     */
    public String getEmpCode() {
        return empCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param empCode セットする empCode
     */
    public void setEmpCode(String empCode) {
        this.empCode = empCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name セットする name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /**
     * @param email セットする email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * @return versionNo
     */
    public Integer getVersionNo() {
        return versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param versionNo セットする versionNo
     */
    public void setVersionNo(Integer versionNo) {
        this.versionNo = versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @return editEmpCode
     */
    public String getEditEmpCode() {
        return editEmpCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param editEmpCode セットする editEmpCode
     */
    public void setEditEmpCode(String editEmpCode) {
        this.editEmpCode = editEmpCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return disableEmpCode
     */
    public boolean isDisableEmpCode() {
        return disableEmpCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param disableEmpCode セットする disableEmpCode
     */
    public void setDisableEmpCode(boolean disableEmpCode) {
        this.disableEmpCode = disableEmpCode;
    }

    /**
     * 初期処理
     */
    @PostConstruct
    @Auth
    public void init(){
        this.setEditEmpCode(FlashUtil.get("empCode"));
        logic.init(this);
    }

    /**
     * 戻るボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String back(){
        // 検索画面に戻る
        return "/views/employee/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    /**
     * 保存ボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String save(){
        logic.save(this);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage("", CommonUtil.getFacesInfoMessage("messages.add.complete"));
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 削除ボタン押下時処理
     * @param empCode
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String delete(){
        logic.delete(this);
        return back();
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * 編集画面のビジネスロジック
 */
@Stateless
public class EditLogicImpl implements EditLogic {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeDao dao;

    /**
     * 初期処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void init(EditBean bean){
        String empCode = bean.getEditEmpCode();
        if(empCode != null){
            Employee employee = dao.findById(empCode);
            bean.setEmpCode(employee.getEmpCode());
            bean.setName(employee.getName());
            bean.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
            bean.setVersionNo(employee.getVersionNo());
            bean.setDisableEmpCode(true);
        }
        if(bean.getVersionNo() == null){
            bean.setVersionNo(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 保存処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void save(EditBean bean){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpCode(bean.getEmpCode());
        employee.setName(bean.getName());
        employee.setEmail(bean.getEmail());
        employee.setVersionNo(bean.getVersionNo());

        if(bean.isDisableEmpCode()){
            // 更新
            dao.update(employee);
            bean.setVersionNo(employee.getVersionNo());
        }else{
            // 新規登録
            dao.insert(employee);
            bean.setDisableEmpCode(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 削除処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(EditBean bean){
        // 削除
        dao.delete(bean.getEmpCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの質問「[エラー原因がわかりません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65320/2808)」の続きかと思いますが、`immediate="true"`を付与してみてください。

```
<h:commandButton class="return" action="#{editBean.back()}" value="戻る" immediate="true" />
```

---

`immediate`属性については公式チュートリアルに正しく説明されており、具体例もあります:

- [10.2.1.2 The immediate Attribute - Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page002.htm#sthref480)

> If the button's `immediate` attribute is set to `true` but the field's `immediate` attribute is set to `false`, the event associated with the button is processed without updating the field's local value to the model layer. The reason is that any events, conversion, and validation associated with the field occur *after* request parameter values are applied.

Comment: ありがとうございました。これで解決しました。immediate="true"のわかりやすい解説ページをもしご存じでしたら教えていただければ幸いです。